# Find the Information of USB Devices In C/C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, usb

I need to list existing USB hub and the devices connected in the hub using my C++ program.

I can able to print the USB Hub and devices connected in hub from terminal using the commands

> lsusb
>   lsusb -v

I want to use that feature in my C++ program.

How I can do this programmatically. Is there any C++ classes available to use in my Qt application or in c or java.this is one help taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61484/find-the-information-of-usb-devices-in-c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>
main(){
struct usb_bus *bus;
struct usb_device *dev;
usb_init();
usb_find_busses();
usb_find_devices();
for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
    for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next){
        printf("Trying device %s/%s\n", bus->dirname, dev->filename);
        printf("\tID_VENDOR = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor);
        printf("\tID_PRODUCT = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idProduct);
    }
```

}
does anyone know how to compile this??? i m facing problem

Comment: How does the question relate to `[java]`?

Comment: this can be solved in c/c++/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install libusb-dev and libusb

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libusb
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

After that compile your code with -lusb

```
gcc usbtest.c -o usbtest -lusb
```

Comment: have u done this type of stff i.e to know the connected devices on linux machine

Comment: thanx now its working...can u share some sample code as i have to show in my company..thanx in advance

Comment: this program is showing many usb devices...i want to know only about mouse,keyboard i.e external devices....can u help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c)

You could use `system()` if you do not need the `stdout`/`stderr`.

You could use `popen()` if you want to capture the `stdout`.

You could use `execlp()` to run the command you desire.
The function call for your question would be something like `execlp("ls","Isusb","Isusb","-v")`
Read this for more information: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execlp.htm